# What are the most effective rideshare sites in the US?

Tags: usa, online-resources, automobiles, ride-sharing

Recently, I have been traveling from upstate New York to NYC quite frequently and would like to find a site that is more effective than craigslist in attracting reliable rideshares for splitting gas and tolls.

Does anyone have any suggestions for other sites? What has been your experience with those sites? Are there any that validate users and have a large user base in the US?

Answer (score 7):

I've had excellent luck with [Craigslist Rideshare](http://portland.craigslist.org/rid/)

Comment: I have used it periodically, but, as a car-owner, it has been unreliable for upstate NY to NYC travel; sometimes, there will be someone interested, but most of the time, there is not. However, it seems as though there are more people traveling there than are posting on Craigslist Rideshare, which is why I inquire.

Comment: I wish there were something better, but I've only ever successfully arranged ride shares in the U.S. (as a rider or as a driver) using Craigslist.

Answer (score 5):

I've used [Carpool World](http://www.carpoolworld.com/) a few times (not in NY) and have always found it quite good. It doesn't have a way to validate users (AFAIK) except based off email. It does charge people money to share their car though so I would assume this would eliminate some crazies.

Answer (score 5):

[Shameless self advertising here](http://www.shareyourride.net/) :)

no outdated listings, no signup required and very easy on your eyes.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be functional as of 2015.

Comment: @schulwitz: It's still online and working for me as of now :)

Answer (score 4):

[Ridester](http://www.ridester.com/) is in beta but looks to be developing into a decent site.  I haven't used it, but it looks much less sketchy than a lot of others and figured it would be worth a shot.  Sorry I can't be more helpful!

Answer (score 3):

I just found [Zimride.com](http://www.zimride.com/) - looks the best looking of all the sites, and connected via Facebook, and payment over the site before people get into your car.

Comment: Was a very useful site, but no longer functional unless you're in their system.

Answer (score 2):

[Liftshare.com](https://www.liftshare.com/uk/) is the largest car-share network in the UK, and  clients include the British Broadcasting Cooperation (BBC), Tesco Supermarkets, Heathrow Airport and the Environment Agency.

It is an off shoot of the american based company. (whose website I can't access).

As I'm in the UK the hyperlink will automatically redirect to the US website.(I hope)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I experienced, http://rideship.com comes my solution for the travel needs of my family and friends. It serves very safe and secured to travelers going to their desired destinations conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

For long distance road trips, [Ridesharemyroute](http://ridesharemyroute.com) is an excellent tool to find and map all of the rideshares from the many craigslist regions overlapping your route.